# Как к Qt Creator присоединить Microsoft SDKs

Tags: qt, qtcreator

У меня проблема , нет отладчика на Qt. 
Использую программы visual-studio_2010-ultimate-x86 ,qt-win-4.8.5-vs2010, qt-creator-2.8.1.

Внутреннего отладчика там нету,  по этому установил Microsoft SDKs по этой инструкции http://datadump.ru/debugging-tools-for-windows/ .

Qt creator как компилятор, SDK видит, но как отладчик (в вкладке инструменты->параметры->Отладчик) нет. печалька ;_;

Но интегрировать в Qt я не смог .

п.с. Пожалуйста не советуйте мне обновить  программное обеспечения (ибо  я привязан к этому)

Comment: Если у вас уже стоит студия - почему бы не использовать ее отладчик?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, QtCreator не может использовать встроенный отладчик Студии, нужно ставить standalone

Answer (score 1):

[Англоязычное руководство](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) указывает, что есть три пути. Я использовал третий - скачал [это](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p?LinkID=271979) и оставил только галку Debugging Tools for Windows.

Потом нужно было рестартануть QtCreator.

Comment: Я как раз скачал и установил только для винды 7. >оставил только галку Debugging Tools for Windows. Где оставил ???? в QtCreator или при установки . Как ты рестартнул  QtCreato r???

Comment: рестартануть QtCtreator - закрыть программу и запустить снова. Но можно и машину ребутнуть (для надежности).